# What is the maximum payload possible in WSMP?

Tags: 802.11p

I searched in google, but I could see `data` is variable but maximum size is not given.

I could not find in IEEE1609.3 as well

Please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSM messages have variable length payloads. The theoretical maximum is 4096 bytes because the `length` field is only 12 bits (4 bits out of 2 bytes are reserved).

However, the recommended variable length of a WSM, including Data, is 1400 bytes as specified in the Annex B of the standard

Comment: hmm missed out. Thanks @kemara